# Problem listening to foreign accents

Tags: american-english, understanding, listening

From the beginning I had some problems listening to foreign accents. Like when someone from my native country (India) speaks English I understand it at once, but if someone from a foreign country especially US speaks English, I have to make them repeat the sentence several times to understand it. Also, I have noticed I have more problems when watching movies, talking than when  watching lectures. I am having lot of trouble these days because of it.

So how can I solve this problem? Also, is there is particular term for this state?

Comment: [This question has now been cross-posted to ELU.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142299/problem-listening-to-foreign-accents)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to focus on **the sound**, rather than the words.

A technique I found especially useful is to try to **transcribe something non-English**. For example, you can challenge yourself to transcribe the lyric of some song that you are sure its lyric is easy to find on the web.

The important point is: you must transcribe it **before you take a peek at the lyric**. Transcribe the whole song if possible. If that is a little too difficult, try to transcribe at least one verse at a time.

For example, I remember I did that with the soundtracks of **Descendants (2011)**. I chose them because it wasn't too difficult, and the music is quite pleasant to listen to repeatedly. (I especially like the song *Ulili E*.) I found that although most parts of the song are easy to transcribe, some of them are quite tricky. :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does transcribing something non-English help you with recognizing the sounds of English?

Comment: It breaks the ice! I found that it is a good way (actually the best way up to this point for me) to make myself realize that there are different sounds in other languages, and they don't have to be the same as they first appeared when I listened to them through my first language ears. In fact, it gave me an experience that I think quite similar to when children learned their first language.

Comment: Once you (the OP) realized that, it will be easier to listen to the "real" sounds of English (or actually any other languages).

Comment: Your mind is very different now than when you learned your first language(s) as a child.  Very young children can recognize the sounds of **all** languages; the adult brain is tuned instead to recognize phonemic contrasts--see e.g. [Werker & Tees 1984](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~port/teach/641/Werker.Tees.crosslg.sp.perceptn.1984.pdf).  The relevant problem, then, is teaching your ear to recognize contrasts between the sets of phonemes used by your L2 languages, in particular those without similar contrasts in your L1 languages.  You cannot do this the same way an infant does.

Comment: @snailboat That's quite true. But I would like to add that though we can't do it exactly the same way as an infant does, we can still achieve a really close result as an adult. What should I call it? Perhaps, a linguist ear, or maybe the third ear.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common. The phonology of Indian English is, for obvious historical reasons, much closer to the native phonology of several languages spoken in India than the phonology of American English is.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English

To learn foreign accents, the best resource is practice. Watch American TV, with subtitles. Try, if possible, to understand what is being said before you check with the subtitle.

If you are interested in phonetics, you may find it helpful to read about syllable-timed vs. stress-timed languages. One interesting phenomenon in Indian English is that it is syllable-timed, rather than stress-timed (most English dialects are stress-timed).

In fact, I used to have a difficult time following native English speakers from India, sometimes, because of this timing distinction. However, with practice, it became much simpler. (For me, having native speakers from India whom I talked with every day is what made it easier. Perhaps you can find a friend from America, maybe over Skype, if this is your goal.)

Comment: I have watched 100's of english movies but there is very less improvment as observed by me. Do you have any other suggestion that works faster?

Comment: Also, I don't have any friend in USA. Also, No one will make me his/her friend just to improve my english.